# How to test if CSS file is linked in head

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to test if there is a link to "css/iframeMobile.css" in an `iframe` on my page. Something like:

```
var isThere = frames['frameName'].document.head.link[href='css/iframeMobile.css'];
```

But I know my syntax is off. Thanks.

Comment: Would'nt you know that be seeing if the styles are applied or not ?

Comment: @adeneo Yes, but there is a greater goal for my question than simply knowing if the styles are applied.

Comment: Is the IFrame page on the same domain?

Comment: @MattCoughlin Yes, otherwise its impossible.

Comment: @adeneo For humans, yes, but the code can't "see"... :P

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use:

```
var isThere = frames['frameName'].document.head.querySelectorAll("link[href='css/iframeMobile.css']").length > 0;
```

to get a boolean.
`querySelectorAll` returns an array of all the elements that you queried for, so if its length is larger than 0, such an element exists.